Cauchy problem for geodesics on a weakly convex Finsler manifold
By a Finsler manifold I shall mean a manifold $M$ equipped with an asymmetric norm $\|\cdot\|$ on each tangent space, such that $\|\cdot\|$ is smooth on the complement of the zero section. In particular $\|\cdot\|$ is strongly convex and so is its dual norm. Under these hypotheses, every geodesic on $M$ is smooth, and given any $(x, \xi) \in TM$ there is a unique maximal geodesic with initial position $x$ and initial velocity $\xi$. Also, I think that if $M$ is forward geodesically complete, then for any $x, y \in M$ there is a geodesic from $x$ to $y$.
Some manifolds are "almost Finsler" in that they are equipped with an asymmetric norm which is NOT smooth. An easy example is $(\mathbb R^d, \|\cdot\|_{\ell^1})$, while a more interesting example is Teichmueller space with Thurston's stretch distance. In these cases it is clear that a minimizing geodesic between two points need not be unique, and geodesics can fail to be $C^1$. Also the geodesic equation doesn't seem to make sense (maybe it does in some distributional sense, but anyways there isn't an obvious way to solve the Cauchy problem).
So let's say I have a smooth manifold $M$ and a Lipschitz function $\|\cdot\|$ on $TM$ which restricts to an asymmetric norm on each tangent space (but I am not assuming strong convexity or smoothness). Are the following conjectures true?

For every $(x, \xi) \in TM$ there is a unique maximal geodesic with initial position $x$ and initial velocity $\xi$.
If $M$ is forward geodesically complete and $x, y \in M$, there is a $C^1$ geodesic from $x$ to $y$.

It's tempting to say that the answer should be "yes" because we can approximate $\|\cdot\|$ by strongly convex norms $\|\cdot\|_n$. But say that $M$ is $\mathbb R^d$ for example, it seems possible that the solutions of the geodesic equation for $\|\cdot\|_n$ have $C^{1 + \alpha}$ norms (with respect to the euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^d$) which become very large at very short times as $n \to \infty$ and arbitrarily small $\alpha > 0$. This doesn't happen when $\|\cdot\|_n$ is the $\ell^{1 + 1/n}$ norm approximating the $\ell^1$ norm, for example, so maybe there is some way to rule it out.
There is a similar MathOverflow question asking for references on these "almost Finsler" manifolds, References on "not-quite" Finsler geometry?, but it doesn't seem to have a satisfactory answer.
